# How to move OpenSSL --extensions v3_ca to config file

Tags: openssl, config

I have an openssl command and a config file for it

```
openssl x509 -req -extfile client.conf -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt --extensions v3_ca
```

**client.conf**:

```
[req]

prompt             = yes
distinguished_name = my_req_dn_prompt
x509_extensions    = v3_ca
req_extensions     = v3_req

[my_req_dn_prompt]

commonName         = Common Name
commonName_max     = 100

countryName        = Country Name
localityName       = City
organizationName   = Organization


[ v3_req ]
keyUsage           = digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage   = clientAuth
basicConstraints   = CA:FALSE

[ v3_ca ]
basicConstraints   = CA:FALSE
keyUsage           = digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage   = clientAuth
```

I need to move OpenSSL `--extensions v3_ca` to the config file so that that command would look like this:

```
openssl x509 -req -extfile client.conf -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt
```

How to do it?